# My two miners in Dwarf Fortress dropped their pickaxes

Tags: dwarf-fortress

My two miners dropped their pickaxes on the floor below right on the stairs. And now they can't mine the area I wanted them to. It's the start of the game and I don't want to have to make a new world.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options:

1. Assign two other dwarves the mining labor, they should go grab the picks. If so, then something has happened to your miners - perhaps they're injured somehow?
2. Make sure the picks are forbidden/marked for dumping or smelting or something.
3. Make sure the miners didn't get activated as soldiers with kits that prevent picks.

As a final option you can try building a weapons stockpile and get the picks moved there - if they don't go, then something is preventing dwarves from interacting with the picks themselves.

Comment: are forbidden -> aren't forbidden. Another possibility (unless this got fixed - it's been years since I've played) is if the miners were also designated as woodcutters. I recall difficulties when workers are supposed to have both a pick and an axe.